# How to reconfigure tkinter canvas items?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I don't know if this question has duplicates , but i haven't found one yet.

when using python you can create GUI fastly , but sometimes you cannot find a method to do what you want. for example i have the following problem:

let's suppose that there is a canvas called K with a rectangle with ID=1(canvas item id , not memory id) in it.

if i want to redraw the item i can delete it and then redraw it with new settings.

```
K.delete(1)
K.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,options...)
```

here is the problem:the object id changes; how can i redraw or move or resize the rectangle or simply change it without changing its id with a method?for example:

```
K.foo(1,options....)
```

if there isn't such a method , then i should create a list with the canvas object ids , but it is not elegant and not fast.for example:

```
ItemIds=[None,None,etc...]
ItemIds[0]=K.create_rectangle(old options...)
K.delete(ItemIds[0])
ItemIds[0]=K.create_rectangle(new options...)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`Canvas.itemconfig`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method):

```
item = K.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,options...)
K.itemconfig(item,options)
```

To move the item, you can use [`Canvas.move`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method)

---

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
item = canvas.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")

def callback():
    canvas.itemconfig(item,fill='red')

button = tk.Button(root,text='Push me!',command=callback)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: could you post an example about how to use that method?

Comment: and if i wanted to change the coordinates of the rectangle?

Comment: You can also use the `coords` method to change the coordinates (ie: to resize it) http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.coords-method

Comment: Here's a working link to the [`coords`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.coords-method) method mentioned in Bryan's comment.

Answer (score 1):

I searched around and found the perfect Tkinter method for resizing.  canvas.coords() does the trick.  just feed it your new coordinates and it's "good to go".  Python 3.4
PS. don't forget the first param is the id.

Comment: please explain your answer more