# How do I delete and create new lines simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to have a line follow the mouse around the canvas. So far I can create the lines but I'm not sure how to delete the old lines, so the screen just fills up with black lines. I would like to delete the old ones but keep the ones that are where the mouse is.
My code is:

```
def evt_motion(self, e):
        plot = Plotter
        self.set_position(e.x, e.y)
        hstart = (e.x, 0)
        hend = (e.x, 1000)
        vstart = (0, e.y)
        vend = (1000, e.y)
        hor = self.canvas.create_line(hstart, hend)
        ver = self.canvas.create_line(vstart, vend)
```

Comment: One way is to draw a new line over the old, using the background colour.  If you don't have to worry about lines crossing, this will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, But I want it to appear as if there are cross-hairs that move with the mouse.

Comment: I have no idea what platform you're using.  Can you declare layers of objects?  If so, then you simply put the cross-hairs on the front layer.  Does your system have the "sprite" concept?  The cross-hairs would make a good sprite.  Otherwise, you could simply delete or overwrite the old icon and then draw a new one.

Comment: Classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you want to move the crosshairs, and you've decided to do that by deleting them and redrawing them. Instead, you should be reconfiguring the object with a new position.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reconfigure tkinter canvas items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212300/how-to-reconfigure-tkinter-canvas-items)

Comment: @Prune: drawing a new line over an old has some fairly bad performance problems in the Tkinter canvas, since the old object still lives in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a line, it returns an identifier. You can use this identifier to delete the line. If, for example, your `hor` and `ver` variables were global, you could use them to delete the old lines.

For example:

```
self.canvas.delete(hor)
self.canvas.delete(ver)
```

You can also apply a tag to the lines so that you don't have to keep track of the ids. One tag can be associated with one or more objects. Giving both lines the same tag means you can delete them both with a single command.

For example:

```
hor = self.canvas.create_line(hstart, hend, tags=("crosshair",))
ver = self.canvas.create_line(vstart, vend, tags=("crosshair",))
...
self.canvas.delete("crosshair")
```

HOWEVER, there's no need to delete and recreate the line. You can simply modify the coordinates of an existing line. By giving each line a unique tag, you can again use the tag rather than the id. This will have significant performance improvements over deleting and recreating the line each time the mouse moves.

For example:

```
hor = self.canvas.create_line(hstart, hend, tags=("hor_line",))
ver = self.canvas.create_line(vstart, vend, tags=("ver_line",))
...
self.canvas.coords("hor_line", e.x, 0, e.x, 1000)
self.canvas.coords("ver_line", 0, e.y, 1000, e.y)
```